# How to create dataframe of conflicting shifts in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, merge

I have two dataframes:

filled_shifts:

```
    Worker ID               Position Name       Start Date  Start Time  End Date    End Time
0   00ul13zkpiYemBsW10x7    Remote CC - Tasks   2020-07-27  5:00:00 AM  2020-07-27  8:00:00 AM  
1   00uk6thr12bpUTTnv0x7    NP CA+NY+DC         2020-07-27  12:00:00 PM 2020-07-27  3:00:00 PM  
2   00umfbwti9WY8UrK30x7    Remote CC - Tasks   2020-07-27  11:00:00 AM 2020-07-27  2:00:00 PM  
3   00uox3mm9oWS9vwSp0x7    NP NY               2020-07-27  9:00:00 AM  2020-07-27  12:00:00 PM 
.....
```

unfilled_shifts:

```
Position Name       Start Date  Start Time  End Date    End Time
Remote CC - Tasks   2020-07-27  5:00:00 AM  2020-07-27  8:00:00 AM  
NP CA+NY+DC         2020-07-27  12:00:00 PM 2020-07-27  3:00:00 PM  
Remote CC - Tasks   2020-07-27  11:00:00 AM 2020-07-27  2:00:00 PM  
NP NY               2020-07-27  9:00:00 AM  2020-07-27  12:00:00 PM 
.....
```

Both dataframes have more rows, these are just some examples. Also the Position Name is not relevant.

I want to see which unfilled_shifts have conflicts with filled_shifts. In other words, if the Unfilled Shift Start Time is >= than the Filled Shift Start Time AND the End Time is <= than the Filled Shift End Time, then we have a conflict.

I was trying to do a merge based on these conditions but it's not working out. Any tips?

Comment: Both dataframes have the exact same start and end dates and times. Can you provide a better sample and also your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge_asof` and then filter as needed:

```
#convert the relevant start and end columns to datetime
filled_shifts["start"] = pd.to_datetime(filled_shifts["Start Date"]+" "+filled_shifts["Start Time"])
filled_shifts["end"] = pd.to_datetime(filled_shifts["End Date"]+" "+filled_shifts["End Time"])

unfilled_shifts["start"] = pd.to_datetime(unfilled_shifts["Start Date"]+" "+unfilled_shifts["Start Time"])
unfilled_shifts["end"] = pd.to_datetime(unfilled_shifts["End Date"]+" "+unfilled_shifts["End Time"])

#merge on the start time 
merged = pd.merge_asof(unfilled_shifts.sort_values("start"), filled_shifts[["start","end"]].sort_values("start"), on="start")

#filter to get conflicts
conflicts = merged[merged["end_x"].ge(merged["end_y"])].drop(columns=["start", "end_x", "end_y"])


>>> conflicts
       Position Name  Start Date   Start Time    End Date     End Time
0  Remote CC - Tasks  2020-07-27   5:00:00 AM  2020-07-27   8:00:00 AM
1              NP NY  2020-07-27   9:00:00 AM  2020-07-27  12:00:00 AM
2  Remote CC - Tasks  2020-07-27  11:00:00 AM  2020-07-27   2:00:00 AM
3        NP CA+NY+DC  2020-07-27  12:00:00 PM  2020-07-27   3:00:00 PM
```